# Issue running rescharper inspect code - dotsettings file not picked up when testing .csproj (c#)

Tags: c#, resharper, code-analysis

I am using Resharper's inspectcode to run analysis on my code.  To do so, I run the following command:

`inspectcode.x86.exe "C:\CODE\src\AI.Core\AI.Core.csproj"
/o:"C:\CODE\analysis\CodeQualityResults.xml" /disable-settings-layers:SolutionPersonal`

My dotsettings file lives here:

```
C:\CODE\src\AI.Core.dotsettings
```

When I run the above command, the settings are not picked up.  Is this because im specifying a project in a folder below the main solution folder.  I.e.:

settings file here:

```
C:\CODE\src\AI.Core.dotsettings
```

project here:

```
C:\CODE\src\AI.Core\AI.Core.csproj
```

*(note: project is a folder below the settings file)*

Why are they not being picked up? What am I doing wrong?  Can the dotsettings file be set as an argument in the command line?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is I think covered in the [documentation for InspectCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/InspectCode.html):

#### *Configuring InspectCode with command-line parameters*

…

*`--profile` — by default, InspectCode will override its default settings with ReSharper settings from the 'Solution team-shared' layer (SolutionName.DotSettings), if it exists. If necessary, **you can use this parameter to specify another .DotSettings file, which will override all other settings.** For example,   --profile="C:\Work\MyRsSettings.DotSettings".*

Comment: Nightmare - can't believe I've completely bypassed this section!! Thanks Stuart!  Will try this now and update my command if it works ok! THANKS

Comment: And confirmed this works like a charm!! Thanks again!